# Why does NumberFormat work in 'ThisWorkbook' but not in a Worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

This VBA script in Excel works perfectly when entered in `'ThisWorkbook'`, but when I enter it in a specific WorkSheet (where I want to link it to a button), it doesn't work, it gives an error on this line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(intStartRow, cell.Column), Cells(lonLowRow, cell.Column)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

The error given is: 1004
```

Does anybody have an idea why and how to remedy it?
Thank you!!

```
Sub proefje()

Dim strTitleRow As String
Dim arrDates() As String
Dim arrTimes() As String
Dim intStartRow As Integer
Dim lonLowRow As Long

strTitleRow = "D5:AW5"
arrDates = Split("Last update,Last recovery test,Date installed,Key valid until", ",")
arrTimes = Split("Time", ",") 
intStartRow = 6
lonLowRow = ActiveSheet.Range("BB3").Value + ActiveSheet.Range("BE3").Value

'Date/Time job start
    ActiveSheet.Range(strTitleRow).Select
    For Each cell In Selection
        If IsInArray(cell.Value, arrDates) Then
          ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(intStartRow, cell.Column), Cells(lonLowRow, cell.Column)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        End If
        If IsInArray(cell.Value, arrTimes) Then
          ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(intStartRow, cell.Column), Cells(lonLowRow, cell.Column)).NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub


Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Please check which value has `lonLowRow` if the error occurs.

Comment: @AxelRichter Value = 35

Comment: Which sheet is *active* when you execute this code? If it's not the sheet which contains the code, you may get a 1004 for unqualified range objects.

Comment: @DavidZemens The script is part of a much bigger script, which cycles through many different sheets. It first selects a sheet, before hitting this part of the code. Also, I'm running it line by line with a good testing sheet active. Even so, changing the code to Sheets(indexnumber). doesn't do the trick. Same error on same line.

Comment: Does it select *this* sheet before running this code?

Comment: Can you change the `ActiveSheet` reference to a specific `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(<"sheet name" or number>)` reference?

Comment: @DavidZemens The first line of code of the Date/Time job start = selecting a range on the active sheet and I can see it do that on the sheet that is opened in Excel, so the script knows what the active sheet is.

Comment: @FreeMan Tried already, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of a Worksheet module, the `Cells` object (unless otherwise qualified) refers to `Me.Cells`, i.e., the worksheet wherein the code resides.  See this simple example which I put in the `Sheet1` module, which will raise the 1004 error when Sheet2 is the ActiveSheet.

```
Sub sheet1Macro()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 2)).Address
End Sub
```

You have a construct like this, which uses the `ActiveSheet`, which may (or may not) be the same sheet.  If `Me` and `ActiveSheet` are not the same sheet, then the error is expected, since you can't define a range which spans multiple worksheets like this.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(intStartRow, cell.Column), Cells(lonLowRow, cell.Column)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End If
```

**Resolution:** put the code in a standard module, or, fully qualify your range objects like:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(.Cells(intStartRow, cell.Column), .Cells(lonLowRow, cell.Column)).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End With
```

Further reading:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)